# Github Actions, docker CiCd build fails due to 403 restriction

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, docker, github-actions, amazon-ecr

i configured a .yml in order to build, increment tag, cache & push the image to ECR.

unfortunately i get 403 forbidden error which should be related to IAM privileges.

This is the error log i am getting.

```
#13 exporting to image
#13 pushing layers 37.6s done
#13 pushing manifest for ***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/ocr:v1@sha256:0fdf68b85ecb6ada3348ec2d1e07fc797056118912f9d2e09fd09b92e1014654
#13 pushing manifest for ***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/ocr:v1@sha256:0fdf68b85ecb6ada3348ec2d1e07fc797056118912f9d2e09fd09b92e1014654 0.2s done
#13 ERROR: failed to push ***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/ocr:v1: unexpected status from HEAD request to https://***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/v2/ocr/manifests/sha256:87f55201ab9885311c1b88b03d27aaaa587aac9b19588b3bd5b2a65d18170891: 403 Forbidden
------
 > exporting to image:
------
WARNING: local cache import at /tmp/.buildx-cache not found due to err: could not read /tmp/.buildx-cache/index.json: open /tmp/.buildx-cache/index.json: no such file or directory
ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push ***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/ocr:v1: unexpected status from HEAD request to https://***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/v2/ocr/manifests/sha256:87f55201ab9885311c1b88b03d27aaaa587aac9b19588b3bd5b2a65d18170891: 403 Forbidden
Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: failed to push ***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/ocr:v1: unexpected status from HEAD request to https://***.dkr.ecr.***.amazonaws.com/v2/ocr/manifests/sha256:87f55201ab9885311c1b88b03d27aaaa587aac9b19588b3bd5b2a65d18170891: 403 Forbidden
```

These are my privileges on IAM.

```
 "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
                "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
                "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
                "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
                "ecr:ListImages",
                "ecr:DescribeImages",
                "ecr:InitiateLayerUpload",
                "ecr:UploadLayerPart",
                "ecr:CompleteLayerUpload",
                "ecr:PutImage"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
```

And here's complete workflow file

```
#Configured Ci/Cd for ocr repo.
#reads aws creds from github secrets, builds tags, pushes images to 'ocr' and caches image to repo 'ocr/cache'
#it defaults to latest tag used in github tag command
#to increment version simply use 'git tag -a v(n) -m 'message' 'git push origin 'tag''

# Define the name of the GitHub Actions workflow
name: Build and Push Docker Image

# Specify when the workflow should be triggered
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master # This workflow triggers on push events to the main branch

# Define the jobs to be run by this workflow
jobs:
  build-and-push:
    # Specify the type of virtual host machine to run the job.
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest # Use the latest Ubuntu runner

    # Define the steps of the job
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        # Use the checkout action to clone your repository code into the GitHub Actions runner
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        # Initializes and sets up Docker Buildx to enable advanced build capabilities like building multi-platform images
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@master
        id: buildx # Assign an ID to this step to reference its outputs later

      - name: Cache Docker layers
        # Caches Docker build layers to speed up subsequent builds by reusing layers.
        uses: actions/cache@v4
        with:
          path: /tmp/.buildx-cache # Path to store the build cache
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-${{ github.sha }} # Unique key for the cache
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-buildx-  # Fallback keys to restore cache from

      - name: Login to Amazon ECR
        # Logs in to Amazon ECR to allow pushing images
        uses: aws-actions/amazon-ecr-login@v2
        env:
          AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }} # Your AWS Access Key ID
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} # Your AWS Secret Access Key

      - name: Fetch the latest tag from ECR
        # Custom script to determine the next tag version by fetching the latest tag and incrementing it
        id: latest-tag
        run: |
          LATEST_TAG=$(aws ecr describe-images --repository-name ocr --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[-1].imageTags[0]' --output text)
          echo "Latest tag is $LATEST_TAG"
          if [[ $LATEST_TAG =~ ^v([0-9]+)$ ]]; then
            NEW_TAG=$((BASH_REMATCH[1] + 1))
            echo "::set-output name=tag::v$NEW_TAG"
          else
            echo "::set-output name=tag::v1"  # Default to v1 if no valid tag is found
          fi
        env:
          AWS_REGION: ${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }} # Replace with your AWS region
          AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }} # Your AWS Access Key ID
          AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }} # Your AWS Secret Access Key

      - name: Build and Push Docker image
        # Builds the Docker image using Buildx and pushes it to the specified ECR repository with the new tag
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
        with:
          context: . # Path to the Docker build context
          builder: ${{ steps.buildx.outputs.name }} # Use the Buildx builder instance created earlier
          push: true # Enable pushing the built image to a registry
          tags: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCOUNT_ID }}.dkr.ecr.${{ secrets.AWS_REGION }}.amazonaws.com/ocr:${{ steps.latest-tag.outputs.tag }} # Tag the image
          cache-from: type=local,src=/tmp/.buildx-cache # Use cache from previous builds
          cache-to: type=local,dest=/tmp/.buildx-cache-new # Store new cache

      - name: Move cache
        # Manages the build cache by cleaning up and preparing for the next build.
        run: |
          rm -rf /tmp/.buildx-cache  # Remove the old cache
          mv /tmp/.buildx-cache-new /tmp/.buildx-cache  # Rename the new cache
```

i have tried building the image and pushing manually using docker build with the same credentials and the push was successful.